# How do we prove a sequence doesn't tend to $+\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we want to prove that the sequence $1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1,\ldots$ doesn't tend to $+\infty.$ Here's what I think we might do:

We negate the definition that says

> $(a_n) \to +\infty \iff \forall C, \exists N $ such that $n > N \implies a_n \ge C.$

So, $(a_n) \not \to +\infty \iff \exists C, \forall N $ such that $n < N$ or  $a_n \ge C.$

I am not clear on what this negation is saying other than finding a $C$ with a certain property. That presupposes that negation was done correctly. My question is what kind of $C$ are we looking for?

Comment: The statement will be easier to understand (and negate) without the implication: $$\forall C, \exists N\text{ s.t. } \forall n > N, a_n \geq C.$$ The negation then is simply $$\exists C, \forall N \exists n > N, a_n < C.$$ In other terms, you need to find some value $C$ such that infinitely many terms of the sequence are less than $C$. (I.e., there is a subsequence bounded above by $C$).

Comment: "does not tend to $+\ infty$" is equivalent to "there exists a bounded-above subsequence". Now, you can easily see that $1,1,1, \dots$ is a bounded subsequence, hence the result.

Comment: @ Clement C, The subsequence we are looking for is $1, 1, 1, 1, 1,\ldots$. We can let $C = 2$. I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your negation isn’t quite right. You’re negating the statement

$$\forall C\in\Bbb R\,\exists N\in\Bbb N\,\forall n>N(a_n\ge C)\;.$$

The negation can be worked out one step at a time:

$$\begin{align*}
\neg\forall C\in\Bbb R\,\exists N\in\Bbb N\,\forall n>N(a_n\ge C)&\equiv\exists C\in\Bbb R\Big(\neg\exists N\in\Bbb N\,\forall n>N(a_n\ge C)\Big)\\
&\equiv\exists C\in\Bbb R\,\forall N\in\Bbb N\Big(\neg\forall n>N(a_n\ge C)\Big)\\
&\equiv\exists C\in\Bbb R\,\forall N\in\Bbb N\,\exists n>N\Big(\neg(a_n\ge C)\Big)\\
&\equiv\exists C\in\Bbb R\,\forall N\in\Bbb N\,\exists n>N(a_n<C)\;.
\end{align*}$$

In words, there is a real number $C$ such for each natural number $N$ there is an $n>N$ with $a_n<C$. This just says that there are a real number $C$ and a subsequence $\langle a_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of the original sequence with the property that $a_{n_k}<C$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$.

Finding such a subsequence of your particular sequence isn’t hard.